# How to normalise outputs of neural networks with different distribution?

Tags: neural-networks, normal-distribution, normalization, skewness, data-preprocessing

I have a `NN` model that predicts 8 different variables. I use a multi-task learning approach, where I compute the loss between predictions and targets for each of the 8 variables, and then I add all the 8 losses together. The sum of the losses is then minimised using gradient descent.

The output variables all have different physical units and ranges. Therefore, I want to normalise the data first before computing the loss. But the problem is, some of the variables are highly skewed, while some are normally (or close to it) distributed.

I need to make sure that all outputs are normalised so that they have values between specific range (e.g. 0 and 1). Because, the original output values for some variables are between 0 and 1, and for some it can be as high as 2000, and for some it can be 50-100.

My question is, should I use the same normalisation algorithm or can I use different normalisation algorithms for different outputs? Which algorithms are recommended for extremely left skewed data?

Comment: If the only reason for normalization is to create a comparable scale (unit interval) then the skew of the distribution is unimportant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are solving a multi-objective optimization problem. If you scalarize your 8 losses to obtain one scalar, then you are selecting one specific pareto optimum from the set of Pareto optimal points. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization

Wikipedia has an example showing that scalarization may not be able to recover all possible Pareto optimal points of the Pareto front if it is non-convex.

This paper suggests some weights which can be chosen for constructing the final objective function = fitness function https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/23311916.2018.1502242

This paper suggests some other scalarization https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020025518307370 which they claim is better when you have more than 3 single objectives.

My take is that there are a lot possible scalarization functions (where normalization may or may not be the first step). In my mind, finding a suitable scalarization comes down do defining the trade-off you are willing to accept. Maybe you can search for more information with the ideas provided here or make your trade-offs more explicit (the needed normalizations will follow from there).

Now a bit more hands-on ideas:
For your multi-task learning approach with losses having different physical units and ranges, it's common to use separate normalization schemes for each losses. You can tailor the normalization to the characteristics of each loss value. For highly skewed values, you might consider using techniques like log transformation or robust scaling to address the skewness and outliers effectively. For normally distributed loss values, standard normalization methods like Min-Max scaling or z-score normalization should work well. Adjust the normalization strategy based on the characteristics of each loss variable to ensure appropriate scaling for all losses.